# Выравнивание align-items не работает

Tags: css, flexbox, align

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  text-decoration: none;
}


/*header Start*/

header {
  width: 100%;
  height: 751px;
  margin: auto;
}

.top_nav {
  width: 100%;
  padding-top: 48px;
}

.sitelogo h2 a {
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  font-size: 25px;
  font-weight: 700;
  line-height: 12px;
  text-decoration: none;
}


/*Топ меню*/

.top_menu {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
}

.top_menu li {
  display: block;
  list-style: none;
  border: 1px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0);
  border-radius: 15px;
}

.top_menu a {
  text-decoration: none;
  font-family: 'Open-Sans', sans-serif;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: 700;
  padding: 30px 10px;
}

.top_menu li:hover {
  border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 1);
  transition: all .2s ease;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<header>
  <div class="container">
    <nav class="top_nav">
      <div class="row justify-content-center  align-items-center">
        <div class="col-md-auto">
          <div class="sitelogo">
            <h2><a href="">BOUNCY</a></h2>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-auto">
          <ul class="top_menu">
            <li><a href="">Hello</a></li>
            <li><a href="">About</a></li>
            <li><a href="">Services</a></li>
            <li><a href="">Portfolio</a></li>
          </ul>
          <!-- /.top_menu -->
        </div>
      </div>
    </nav>
    <!-- /.top_nav -->
  </div>
</header>
```

Comment: `margin` у `.top_menu` уберите

Answer (score 0, accepted):

У Вас есть файл `reboot.css`, от которого наследуются стили в Ваш документ. 
Вы должны в класс `.top_menu` написать свойства `margin` со значением, либо `margin: 0` `margin-bottom: 0`. Это меню представленно у Вас, как список `ul`, для которого в файле `reboot.css` задано свойство `margin-bottom: 1rem`, поэтому и **обнулите** его.